# Hibernate - Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion

Tags: java, hibernate

After a few queries get executed I'm getting the following message from Hibernate:

```
HHH000106: Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion
```

Everything seems to be working fine, there are no errors, but I haven't found any explanation as to what this message means, or if I should do anything about it.

I'm using Hibernate/JPA with JTA global transactions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set the property `hibernate.connection.release_mode` to `on_close` and see if you are still getting the message.

Comment: he obviously googled before asking the question. I don't think he is looking for that solution, I might be wrong however

Comment: Well, I'm looking for an explanation, not necessarily a solution :)

Comment: That is an INFO log. Its not a warning or error so there is no need to do any thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(To complete xwoker's answer.)

The resources we are talking about are:

- ResultSet
- Statement

This message occurs because you left some of those resources *open* i.e. you didn't call  their `close()` method. Due to the current ConnectionReleaseMode: those resources became useless and Hibernate informs you that it is calling the close() method for you.

To avoid this log: just call the close() method (on your ResultSet(s) and Statement(s)) yourself before the end of the transaction.

Comment: Indeed, found, closed and fixed - I can sleep in peace now :)

Answer (score 6):

This message is produced in the **org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl** (at least is that the only place I found it used) and is declared as **INFO**:

```
public void afterTransaction() {
    transactionTimeOutInstant = -1;
    if ( connectionReleaseMode() == ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_STATEMENT ||
            connectionReleaseMode() == ConnectionReleaseMode.AFTER_TRANSACTION ) {
        if ( hasRegisteredResources() ) {
            LOG.forcingContainerResourceCleanup();
            releaseResources();
        }
        getLogicalConnection().aggressiveRelease();
    }
}
```

If certain ConnectionReleaseModes are used and there are registered resources, Hibernate informs you, that it releases these resources.

If this is the desired behaviour, don't do anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

This log message `HHH000106: Forcing container resource cleanup on transaction completion` can also be triggered by thread safety problems, if Hibernate sessions are accidentally shared between different threads (and thus different transactions).  If so, it may be followed by an exception like `Trying to return an unknown connection2!` and leaking a JDBC connection from the connection pool.